# Is it bad practice to include a .cpp file when your implementation file is a templated class?

Tags: c++

I have a template class that I want to separate from my main.cpp file, where I'll be conducting tests, etc. The problem I have is that there's no easy way to separate the template class into .h/.cpp files because the compiler needs to know which type(s) the object may potentially be.

I came across [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp) resource and I'm primarily looking at "Method 2." Is it bad practice to include a .cpp file in the file that holds main?
I've always been told that it was generally unadvised, but what would be the best solution here?

Comment: Make a header file and put there your template class. Then include the implementation (i.e., the cpp file) in that header. Then include the header of the template class in main.cpp

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's bad practice.

It's also bad practice to include it in the corresponding header.

What if someone tries to compile the project by giving all `.cpp` files as input to the compiler?

Good practice would be to mark those special files with a special extension, usually `.inl`.

Comment: This is a good answer. Except, I would point out that there are *no* advantages in splitting definitions of member functions of template classes into a separate file.

Comment: @user2079303 Clarity? Separation? Consistency with (non-template) `.h`/`.cpp`? (personally I prefer to put everything in the header)

Comment: Templates are not classes. They don't behave consistently, so what's the advantage in treating them consistently?

Comment: They _are_ not, but their _structure_ is exactly the same. Therefore it would make sense to make their _representation_ the same as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `#include` the `.cpp` into the corresponding `.h`? This will solve the template compilation problem and at the same time follow the standard approach with non-templated classes.

`SomeClass.h`:

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

template<class T>
class SomeClass { /* ... */ };

#include "SomeClass.cpp"

#endif
```

`SomeClass.cpp`:

```
template<class T> SomeClass::foo() 
/*...*/
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "SomeClass.h"

int main() { 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

Just don't forget that you do not need to actually *compile* your `SomeClass.cpp`. As suggested by others, you might choose a different extension (not `.cpp`) for the implementation file.

UPD: on reading the article you linked, I see that this is called "Method 3".

Comment: Clarifying questions should go in the comments, not as part of the answer. You should fix it before it gets down-voted.

Comment: @ray that could be a rhetorical question.

Comment: @ray, I do not think this was a question expecting an answer, let alone clarifying question. However, I removed it.

Comment: No problem. The question just came across differently to me.

Comment: @Petr Having the template implementation in a `.cpp` file will confuse many build systems and IDE's though. It's better to use a different file extension like `.tcc` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Best: let the class template implementation be part of the header.

Then you have

- MyClass.hpp

Only separate the implementation out as a distinct file if there ever will be a need for the header's code without the implementation code.

Because if the code sans implementation will not ever be needed, there is no rationale for using a distinct file.

---

However. if you separate the implementation as a distinct file, make that a header too, because that's how it's intended to be used. It's not intended to be separately compiled. And you don't want some too smart IDE to do that.

Then, because **headers should be self-contained**, the implementation should include the purely declarative header, like this:

- MyClass.fwd.hpp
  Pure declarations.
- MyClass.hpp
  Includes the above pure header.

This then is structured very much like the standard library's `<ioswfd>`, which corresponds to MyClass.fwd.hpp above.

Comment: "there is no rationale for using a distinct file." -- will not it still be easier for the users of template class, that they will not see the implementation if they do not need it? Surely you can put all the members definitions after the class definition, but still will not having it in a separate file be easier to read?

Comment: @Petr: Re readability I can only answer for myself, and my thinking is that what users need, documentation, is a separate thing. If the code is its own documentation then I prefer it all in one file. If the code grows too large for reasonable scrolling then techniques such as collapsable regions can be employed.