# C++ : Error Redefinition & Previously Declared

Tags: c++

I am half way into my course.I am unable to understand the logic behind the errors I am receiving. I have already tried to counter it by using appropriate directives at the bottom of my Array.h file. I am receive the following 2 errors across all functions:

1. **note: 'const T& udbhavAg::Container::Array::operator const' previously declared here
   const T &Array::operator[](int index) const {**
2. **error: redefinition of 'const T& udbhavAg::Container::Array::operator const'
   const T &Array::operator[](int index) const {**

My questions are the following :

1. Why are the files being declared twice?
2. Why are they being redefined?

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Line.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Array.h"
#include "ArrayException.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace udbhavAg::CAD;
using namespace udbhavAg::Container;
using namespace udbhavAg;

int main()
{
    Array<Point> points(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Array.h

```
#include "Point.h"
#include <cstring>
#include "ArrayException.h"
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H
//#include "Array.cpp"

namespace udbhavAg
{
    namespace Container
    {
        template <typename T>
        class Array {
        private:
            T *m_data;
            int m_size;

        public:
            Array();

            Array(int size);

            Array(const Array &obj);

            virtual ~Array();

            //const Array operator= ( const Array & source);
            Array<T> &operator=(const Array &source);

            int Size() const;

            void setElement(int index, T p);

            T &getElement(int index) const;

            T &operator[](int index);

            const T &operator[](int index) const;
        };
    }
}

#ifndef Array_cpp // Must be the same name as in source file #define
#include "Array.cpp"
#endif

#endif ARRAY_H
```

Array.cpp

```
#include "Array.h"
#include "ArrayException.h"


namespace udbhavAg
{
    namespace Container
    {
        template<typename T>
        Array<T>::Array():m_size(3),m_data(new T[m_size]) {}

        template<typename T>
        Array<T>::Array(int size): m_size(size), m_data(new T[m_size]) {}

        template<typename T>
        Array<T>::~Array()
        {
            delete[] m_data;
            cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
        }

        template<typename T>
        Array<T>::Array(const Array &obj) {
            m_size = obj.m_size;

            m_data = new CAD::Point[m_size];

            for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
            {
                m_data[i] = obj.operator[](i);
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        int Array<T>::Size() const
        {
            return m_size;
        }

        template<typename T>
        T &Array<T>::getElement(int index) const
        {

            try
            {
                if (index >= m_size || index < 0)
                    {
                        throw (OutofBoundsException(index));
                    }
                else
                    {
                        return m_data[index];
                    }
            }
            catch (ArrayException &error)
            {
                cout << error.GetMessage();

            }

        }

        template<typename T>
        void Array<T>::setElement(int index, T p)
        {

            try
            {
                if (index >= m_size || index < 0)
                {
//                    OutofBoundsException error = OutofBoundsException(index);
//                    ArrayException& abc = error;
                    throw (OutofBoundsException(index));
                }
                else
                {
                    m_data[index] = p;
                }
            }
            catch (ArrayException &error)
            {
                cout << error.GetMessage();

            }

        }

        template<typename T>
        Array<T> & Array<T>::operator=(const Array &source)
                {
                    if(&source != this){ //edited self assignment test
                        if(m_size != source.m_size){//diff sized arrays
                            delete [] m_data; //reclaim space
                            m_size = source.m_size;
                            m_data = new CAD::Point[m_size]; //space created
                        }
                    }
                    for(int i=0; i<m_size; i++){
                        m_data[ i ] = source.m_data[i];}

                    return *this;     //enables cascading a=b=c
                }

        template<typename T>
        T &Array<T>::operator[](int index) {

            try
            {
                if (index >= m_size || index < 0)
                {
//                        OutofBoundsException error = OutofBoundsException(index);
//                        ArrayException& abc = error;
                    throw (OutofBoundsException(index));
                }
                else
                {
                    return m_data[index];
                }
            }
            catch (ArrayException &error)
            {
                cout << error.GetMessage();

            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        const T &Array<T>::operator[](int index) const {

            try
            {
                if (index >= m_size || index < 0)
                {
//                        OutofBoundsException error = OutofBoundsException(index);
//                        ArrayException& abc = error;
                    throw (OutofBoundsException(index));
                }
                else
                {
                    return m_data[index];
                }
            }
            catch (ArrayException &error)
            {
                cout << error.GetMessage();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all your headers wrapped in an if def guard?

Comment: It is better to use #pragma at the beginning of every header

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 assuming you mean `#pragma once`, not really because that is not standardised, so it's not necessarily portable, so many prefer not to rely upon it.

Comment: see also [Is it bad practice to include a .cpp file when your implementation file is a templated class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432556/is-it-bad-practice-to-include-a-cpp-file-when-your-implementation-file-is-a-tem) - spoiler: yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably because in Array.h :

> ```
> #ifndef Array_cpp // Must be the same name as in source file #define
> #include "Array.cpp"
> #endif
> ```

so Array.cpp `#include Array.h` whose `#include Array.cpp` because `Array_cpp` is not defined

Do not include source file in your header files

Out of that why in Array.h

> ```
> #ifndef ARRAY_H
> #define ARRAY_H
> ```

is not at the beginning of the file ?

---

So possible exclusive solutions to solve are :

- to remove `#include "Array.h"` at the beginning of Array.cpp
- to add `#define Array_cpp` to be the very first line in Array.cpp

in both case you must not compile Array.cpp in your Makefile or equivalent nor link with it.

But the best one is to replace in Array.h

> ```
> #ifndef Array_cpp // Must be the same name as in source file #define
> #include "Array.cpp"
> #endif
> ```

by the definitions from the file Array.cpp and to delete the file Array.cpp.

The template classes are special, all template methods must be defined in the header file and only in it, not in a source file also compiled as a 'normal' source file, the compiler does the stuff for you

Comment: Initial that we the format in which I did it. The code above is after multiple tries of changing little things around.

Comment: If I do not include the Array.cpp in the Array.h file the following error is thrown:

**undefined reference to `udbhavAg::Container::Array<udbhavAg::CAD::Point>::Array(int)'**

Comment: @UdbhavAgarwal I edited my answer to add proposals to solve your problem

Comment: Template functions _can_ be defined in separate source files / translation units, if those TUs use explicit instantiation to generate the required instantiations. It's just that doing so means you need to know ahead of time which types/values you must instantiate for, and many users don't.

Comment: Yes, i have solved the issue using your solution. I was missing the definition of the Array.cpp file. Thanks for your help @bruno